# Autofac is resolving duplicate instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to get a list of all validators of a particular command using Autofac. I have created an interface

```
    public interface IValidate<T>
    {
        void Validate(T command);
    }
```

And I have implemented 2 validators for this interface

```
    public class ValidateRule1 : IValidate<CreateEnrollmentCommand>
    {
        public void Validate(CreateEnrollmentCommand command)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ValidateRule2 : IValidate<CreateEnrollmentCommand>
    {
        public void Validate(CreateEnrollmentCommand command)
        {
        }
    }
```

I am injecting these validators in an IEnumerable like this

```
public class MyCommandHandler
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidate<CreateEnrollmentCommand>> _validators;

    public MyCommandHandler(IEnrollmentRepository enrollmentRepository, IEnumerable<IValidate<CreateEnrollmentCommand>> validators)
    {
        _enrollmentRepository = enrollmentRepository;
        _validators = validators;
    }
 }
```

Here is my Autofac Configuration

```
    public class AutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // Register API Assembly
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

            // Register Data Access
            var api = typeof(CreateStudentCommand).Assembly;
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(api)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

            // Register Data Access
            var dataAccess = typeof(StudentRepository).Assembly;
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();


            builder
                .RegisterType<Mediator>()
                .As<IMediator>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
            {
                var c = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return t => c.Resolve(t);
            });

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CreateStudentCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces(); // via assembly scan
        }
    }
```

I am expecting two validators to be injected by Autofac, but it is actually injecting 2 instances of each validator. I am getting total of 4 validator instances in the IEnumerable property. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
The IValidate interface and the validators are all located in the same assembly as pointed out by @Lasse V. Karlsen

Comment: Are the validators and the CreateStudentCommand type in the same assembly? In fact, can you note which types are in which assemblies, for clarity? Also, it looks like you're registering the assembly types for the assembly with the CreateStudentCommand type twice, once under the "// Register Data Access" comment, and once at the bottom.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes you are right, the validation interface and the validators are all located in the Application assembly. I will delete that extra registration and see if that is causing the issue.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen mate that was exactly the problem, I had the registration defined twice! You saved my day. Can you post your comment as an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several calls that register all types in an assembly, in particular I would check:

- The duplicate registration of all types in the assembly that contains the `CreateStudentCommand` type
- Whether all the types used to identify "all types in assembly" are in separate assemblies